# Where can I find out what each of the variables in the node fs package's fs.Stats object are?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out what information is included in the fs.Stats object referenced at: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties listed on that page are not node-specific, which is why they didn't bother documenting them. You can find information about them with a general search for `fstat`.

This [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

When push comes to shove, you could always right a loop that prints all of an objects properties to the console. I've never done this in node.js before, but it should look like...

```
for (var name in myObj)
  console.log(name + ": " + myObj[name]);
```

That's the most sure fire method I know of.

Comment: I know the names of all of the variables but I'm curious what data they actually represent.